# How to download a file from sub domain which is available on domain in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

**How to download a file from sub domain  which is available on domain in asp.net C Sharp**

suppose I have a file  **abc.doc** on example.com

but now I want to download this file **abc.doc** from  admin.example.com ,

how it is possible in asp.net C sharp

I  tried lots of code but it is showing is not a valid virtual path.

This is the code which I  used.

```
string strURL = "`http://example.com/resume.doc`";
    WebClient req = new WebClient();
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Server.MapPath(strURL) + "\"");
    byte[] data = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(strURL));
    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.End();
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to explain yourself a bit better. It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: I have tried to explain better, Please  guide me now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Server.MapPath` on an URL. You can't do that since the URL isn't on your server file system. Remove that and you can download your file.

```
byte[] data = req.DownloadData(strURL);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Mr. Sami ,                                                                     I have  removed as you have suggested by it is showing error    is not a valid virtual path

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for quick reply Mr. Sami ,                                                                     I have  removed as you have suggested by it is showing error                        http://example.com/resume.doc is not a valid virtual path. My new code is  string code is

string strURL = "`http://example.com/resume.doc`";
    WebClient req = new WebClient();
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Server.MapPath(strURL) + "\"");
       response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.End();